# Why property not accessible in Python?

Tags: python, class, subclass

GenericWidget is needed for rendering low-level elements, such as squares or text. They have a predefined size. Rendering is described in the render function. The Widget class has a build method, which should return the widgets that make up the widget that we make. The context (parent widget) must be passed to the build method. The problem is that when you try to get the widget size, there is a problem that the size parameter does not exist.

Here my example code:

```py
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.__context__ = context
        self.__update_instance__()

    def build(self, context):
        return NotImplemented

    def render(self, xy):
        self.__update_instance__()
        self.__instance__.render(xy=xy)

    def __update_instance__(self):
        self.__instance__ = self.build(context=self.__context__)
        self.size = self.__instance__.size


class GenericWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        super(GenericWidget, self).__init__(self)

    def build(self, context):
        return self


class GenericTest(GenericWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GenericTest, self).__init__(size=(10, 10))

    def render(self, xy):
        # all rendering core here
        pass


class Test2(Widget):
    def build(self, context):
        print(context.size)
        return GenericTest()


class Test(Widget):
    def build(self, context):
        return Test2(self)


class OwnWidget(Widget):
    def build(self, context):
        return Test(self)


class Spacer(GenericWidget):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Spacer, self).__init__(size=size)


OwnWidget(Spacer((100, 100))).render(xy=(0, 0))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
    OwnWidget(Spacer((100, 100))).render(xy=(0, 0))
  File test.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.__update_instance__()
  File "test.py", line 14, in __update_instance__
    self.__instance__ = self.build(context=self.__context__)
  File "test.py", line 49, in build
    return Test(self)
  File "test.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.__update_instance__()
  File "test.py", line 14, in __update_instance__
    self.__instance__ = self.build(context=self.__context__)
  File "test.py", line 44, in build
    return Test2(self)
  File "test.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.__update_instance__()
  File "test.py", line 14, in __update_instance__
    self.__instance__ = self.build(context=self.__context__)
  File "test.py", line 38, in build
    print(context.size)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Why `size` property are not accessible?

Comment: Stop giving your attributes and methods double-u names.

Comment: `Test` inherits from `Widget` (which has no `size` attribute), not `GenericWidget` (which does).

Comment: But I call `__update_instance__` in `__init__` witch sets the size property.